# module.exports returns undefined in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `fs.readFile` to read the content of `config.json` in `readCredentials.js`. Then I am exporting the function so I can use it it `config.js`.

When I run `node config.js` I get two `undefined` and then real values of `username` and `password` in `config.js`. Any idea how i can fix this?

**readCredentials.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./config.json", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  const config = JSON.parse(data);
  const username = config.username;
  const password = config.password;
  console.log(username, password);
  module.exports = { username, password };
});
```

**config.json**

{
"username": "xyz",
"password": "xyz"
}

**config.js**

```
const { username, password } = require("./readCredentials.js");

const usernameValue = username;

const passwordValue = password;

console.log(usernameValue, passwordValue);
```

Comment: a) don't use the asynchronous version of `readFile` or b) log the imported values only after the file was read. Easiest when you export a promise for the values.

Comment: When you import from `readCredentials.js`, the `fs` is still in the process of reading the file. In your case [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a CommonJS module, you cannot assign `module.exports` as the result of any asynchronous operation.  This is because the whole loading process does not wait for your asynchronous operation to complete.

As such, the consumer of that export will be using its value BEFORE it has been assigned by your asynchronous operation.

In an ESM module and recent version of nodejs, you can use use top level `await` with promises to accomplish something like this.

But, since this is just part of the module loading process, you can just switch to synchronous I/O using `fs.readFileSync()` or just use `require()` which can load and parse `.json` files for you automatically and solve your problem that way.

```
const { username, password } = require("./config.json");
module.exports = { username, password };
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way out could be to use plain `require` instead (it can read and parse json files just fine). An alternative would be `readFileSync`, as above.

**readCredentials.js**

```
const config = require("./config.json");
const username = config.username;
const password = config.password;
console.log(username, password);
module.exports = { username, password };
```